# Create interface configuration files using Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I've saved as a CSV file (comma deliminated) containing the IP addresses of multiple interfaces for a list of servers. There's been an interface configured on these servers (initially) so I have connectivity. I'd like to go through this file row-by-row and grab the necessary values to build the ifcfg file locally, copy to the server and then restart the network.

This is not the actual file; rather, a sample outlining the idea that there's a location with multiple IP addresses provided.

```
New Orleans, 192.168.10.42, 13, 192.168.3.10
Atlanta, 192.168.31.100, 18, 192.168.10.10
Detroit, 172.16.31.8, 43, 172.16.10.27
```

The goal is to parse this file and create the network interface files as follows

ifcfg-eth0

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED=no
IPADDR=192.168.10
```

ifcfg-ens3

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED=no
IPADDR=192.168.3.10
```

This looks to get me partway there

```
- debug:
  loop: "{{ lookup('file', './file.one').splitlines() }}"
  register: val
```

And returns

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=New Orleans, 192.168.10.42, 13, 192.168.3.10) => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Atlanta, 192.168.31.100, 18, 192.168.10.10) => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Detroit, 172.16.31.8, 43, 172.16.10.27) => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
```

I did find a snippet on StackOverflow using `the_dict` I used but everything is returned as a list and not a scalar :(

```
  tasks:
  - debug: var=the_dict
    vars:
      the_dict: >-
        {%- set row = lookup("file", "~/Documents/Book1.csv").split("\n") | list -%}
        {%- for i in row -%}
        {%- set v  = i.split(",") -%}
        {%- set A_Location = v.0 -%}
        {%- set B_Interface = v.1 -%}
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: i dont see how you go from the csv file to your other files? the fist data is just ip partial..so could you precise? and what do you want as result, dictionary, reporting string .... your question is not enough precise

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. The Excel spread sheet is just saved as CSV - there's no automation. The resulting file is comma delaminated which I'm trying to parse taking the necessary values to fill in the interface config file. The idea is I'll take the CSV file row-by-row, build the interface file locally, copy that file to the appropriate server and then restart the network. Hoping that makes sense. I'll better update my question.

Comment: i have created a template you could adapt see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to read csv with ansible, read [module CSV](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/read_csv_module.html)

an example to use template
the template file conf.j2 (to put in templates directory)

```
{% for record in  records.list %}
ifcfg-eth0

TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED=no
IPADDR={{ record.ip1 }}

ifcfg-ens3

TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED=no
IPADDR=1{{ record.ip2 }}

{% endfor %} 




- name: playbook2.0
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Read CSV file and return a list
      community.general.read_csv:
        path: file.csv
        fieldnames: location,ip1,data,ip2
        delimiter: ','
      register: records
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: generate fileconf.txt from conf.j2
      template:
        src: conf.j2
        dest: fileconf.txt
```

you have the new file conf generated in the file fileconf.txt

you could adapt the file.j2 as you want with jinja2 syntax